# How to correct the order of the year in Qliksense?

Tags: qliksense

My data contain a column showing the year of each record, ranging from 2005 to 2017 I am using the `Time Slide` extension (https://github.com/caallard/Time-slide) to help me visualize the data. However, the order of the year is problematic.

As shown in the following plot, the first year in the slider is  `2006`, while the last year is `2005`, which means the first year somehow shifted to the last.

[image]

[image]

I further checked my data. When I uploaded my data to the `Qliksense`, the preview of the data in the data manager window looks like the following. The year is not in the right order. Perhaps this is related to my question.

[image]

I would like to learn how can I fix this. Thanks.

#### Edit

I have a workaround for now. There are two tables in my Qlik sense both have a column showing `Year`. Previously I linked these two tables with the `Year` column. I just deleted that link, and reference my `time slide` to the `Year` column from the other table. The sequence of the year in my `time slide` is normal now.

Here is the preview of the year column from my other table. The order of the year is normal, and I believe since I added this column to my `time slide`, the order of the `time slide` is normal accordingly.

[image]

However, the original year column I showed before is still in the wrong order. This is strange.

#### Edit 2

If I select the `Time Slide` extension in edit mode, below is the available under the `Dimension`. For the `Sort by Numeric` and `Sort by Alphabetical`, they both have three options: `No`, `Ascending`, and `Descending`. However, switching between these options does not affect the order of the year  in `Time Slide`.

[image]

Comment: Thats odd indeed. What is your dimension (`Year`) order?

Comment: @StefanStoichev Thank you for your comments. Please see my update. I have a  workaround for now, but the order of the original `year` column is still wrong, which is interesting. If you don't mind, could you explain how can I check the dimension order? When I preview the `Year` column, there are no other buttons or input fields for me to adjust the order.

Comment: (when you are in Edit mode) select the chart and on the right-hand side menu expand the `Sorting` properties, expand the `Year` property. By default the sorting is set to `Auto`. This means that Qlik will decide for you. Deactivate the `auto` by clicking on the slider and there you can "play" with the sorting options

Comment: @StefanStoichev Thank you. Please see my update again. Changing the options related to sort does not affect the order of the year.